# Multiple map layers : TPK

Tags: arcgis-desktop, offline, tile-package

Working on ARCGIS for Offline mapping ,Can a tpk file have multiple map layers inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tile package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000457000000) (.tpk) file is a product of rasterization of your map document (.mxd) which can contain multiple layers.

This is essentially the same as caching map services if you more familiar with this concept.

Comment: thanks @Alex , One more doubt..is it possible to perform query tasks in TPK files?

Comment: A tile package is just a bunch of raster files so no vector data is included. You can, however, obtain information about the extent, scales included and other metadata provided partially in xml and in json.